# React loop with nested props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I loop this props?

[image]

Tried looping something like this:

```
for (var key in this.props.data.data) {

    this.state.newData.push(
        <NewData key={key} />
    );
}
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use setState to change the state:

```
var newArr = [];
for (var key in this.props.data.data) {
    newArr.push(<NewData key={key} />);
}
this.setState( {newData: newArr });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work:

```
const newData = this.props.data.data.map(key => (<NewData key={key} />));
this.setState({ newData });
```

Two notable changes:

1. Using `Array.prototype.map` to iterate over the array rather than a `for`-`in` loop.
2. Using `setState` to set the state rather than doing so directly. Outside of the constructor, you should always use `setState`. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html for more details.